# WPF Image rotating and moving forward at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

Is there something similar to do like in the sample Picture if I use `Image`? I have `Canvas` where I placed `Image`(red dot is an `RenderTransformOrigin`) and I want to move that `Image` like it's shown down below (green line is move trajectory).

> Sample Picture:
>   [image]

I imagine that it should move quarter of circle...

> Maybe there is engine or something similar I described, or maybe you have other solutions? Help my to figure it out.

Comment: @Clements, the question you marked as duplicate does not have an answer.

Comment: Yes, it does, look in the comments

Comment: @EmperorAiman That's no reason to ask the same question again. OP hasn't even responded to suggestions made in comments.

Comment: @Clemens, oh. I didn't notice it was the same person.